# Text justification in an overleaf template

Tags: overleaf

I am using the following template for my PFE report: https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/enetcom-template/kmgfwggdmvgy The sample text in the template seems to be justified, but when i put my own text some words exceed the line(left rigged)  , the template use .cls file for the style and i have tried many solutions on the internet to justify the text like importing the "ragged2e" package and using the "\justifying" command but it still doesn't work. Can anyone help me? you can check the image below[image: output example for my own text]

Comment: The pdf template shows justified paragraphs, in normal text. It is not clear your problem. Please, clarify.

Comment: as Sigur commented [the sample output is justified](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TIblJ.png)

Comment: Then please create a MWE showing that some words go past the end of the line (which is a different issue than left-aligned).  And what images are you talking about?

Comment: Thank you all for your support. I am a new user and i had difficulties to add images in the comment section. So i modifiyed the main question to be more readable.

Comment: The template has indented paragraphs while your image does not.  Could you create a [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/107497) with the offending paragraph?  It should only require three or four packages.

Comment: Even with indented parpagraphs the text is not justified.

Comment: tex clearly _is_ justifying the text as you can see by the right margin. It failed on one line and would have warned about that. assuming you have specified french setup you could give it some help eg `climatiq\-ues` or use `\sloppy` or any other approach to handling overfull boxes.

Comment: if you have not `\usepackage[french]{babel}`  or equivalent, latex will try to hyphenate French words using English  dictionary which will often fail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Line 254 of the cls file has

```tex
% Remove hyphens
\hyphenpenalty=10000
\exhyphenpenalty=10000
```

If you don't let TeX hyphenate, then you end up with bad line breaks.  Comment out those lines.  And maybe comment out the packages that get loaded twice.  And maybe rethink using that (or any) template.

Comment: I really appreciate your help. Commenting those lines solved the problem for me.